# Mod_rewrite redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/galerie$ galerie.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/galerie/$ galerie.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/galerie-(.*)_(.*)$ galerie_poze.php?user=$1&album=$2&page=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/galerie-(.*)_(.*)/$ galerie_poze.php?user=$1&album=$2&page=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php?$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and it doesnt seem to work.

Here is my problem: when I want to access a page on my site e.g. `site.com/test.php`,
it redirects to `index.php?request=test`. The problem is that I also have "profil.php" and "galerie.php" that I dont want to pass through `index.php`. Instead when I do this: `site.com/username/profil`, I want it to point to `profil.php?user=username`, but it doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i've put something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.php?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php?$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/personal$ personal.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/personal/$ personal.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/galerie$ galerie.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/galerie/$ galerie.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/galerie-(.*)_(.*)$ galerie_poze.php?user=$1&album=$2&page=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/galerie-(.*)_(.*)/$ galerie_poze.php?user=$1&album=$2&page=$3 [NC]
```

and when i do /username or /username/profil it works BUT it no longer works with the first rule id i do sitename.tld/test.php it doesnt work....

Comment: i forgot to mention that the site has 2 profil.php (the first one shows the profile to a guest, and the second one shows logged in users their profiles) all the site functionality goes trough index.php, and what we show to guests is in those 3 files (personal.php, profil.php and galerie.php/galerie_poze.php)

Answer (score 0):

You want one of your two first rules to match `[username]/profil` (where it now matches `[username]` and `[username]/`)

Try

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/profil$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC, L]
```

Comment: the thing is it doesnt work... it redirects to index.php?request=user/profil

Answer (score 0):

Use conditionals.

Make sure the file or directory doesn't exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You can also restrict redirects by using something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profil\.php$ [NC]
```

Make sure to properly escape.
This needs to be escaped:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php?$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php?$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

Can be simplified to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profil.php?user=$1 [NC]
```